# can't concat string to bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, twitter

I'm trying grab twitter user data by their screen name using python.
The entire script does is to loop over each of the Twitter accounts in the ids variable — and for each one it will grab its profile information and add that to a row of the output file.
but I'm getting an error.

This is my code

```
// LIST OF TWITTER USER IDS
ids = "4816,9715012,13023422, 13393052,  14226882,  14235041, 14292458, 14335586, 14730894,\
   15029174, 15474846, 15634728, 15689319, 15782399, 15946841, 16116519, 16148677, 16223542,\
   16315120, 16566133, 16686673, 16801671, 41900627, 42645839, 42731742, 44157002, 44988185,\
   48073289, 48827616, 49702654, 50310311, 50361094,"

// THE VARIABLE USERS IS A JSON FILE WITH DATA ON THE 32 TWITTER USERS LISTED ABOVE
users = t.lookup_user(user_id = ids)

//NAME OUR OUTPUT FILE - %i WILL BE REPLACED BY CURRENT MONTH, DAY, AND YEAR
outfn = "twitter_user_data_%i.%i.%i.txt" % (now.month, now.day, now.year)

// NAMES FOR HEADER ROW IN OUTPUT FILE
fields = "id screen_name name created_at url followers_count friends_count statuses_count \
   favourites_count listed_count \
   contributors_enabled description protected location lang expanded_url".split()

// INITIALIZE OUTPUT FILE AND WRITE HEADER ROW   
outfp = open(outfn, "w")
//outfp.write(string.join(fields, "\t") + "\n")  # header
outfp.write("\t".join(fields) + "\n")  # header

// THIS BLOCK WILL LOOP OVER EACH OF THESE IDS, CREATE VARIABLES, AND OUTPUT TO FILE


for entry in users:
   // CREATE EMPTY DICTIONARY
   r = {}
   for f in fields:
       r[f] = ""
   // ASSIGN VALUE OF 'ID' FIELD IN JSON TO 'ID' FIELD IN OUR DICTIONARY
   r['id'] = entry['id']
   // SAME WITH 'SCREEN_NAME' HERE, AND FOR REST OF THE VARIABLES
   r['screen_name'] = entry['screen_name']
   r['name'] = entry['name']
   r['created_at'] = entry['created_at']
   r['url'] = entry['url']
   r['followers_count'] = entry['followers_count']
   r['friends_count'] = entry['friends_count']
   r['statuses_count'] = entry['statuses_count']
   r['favourites_count'] = entry['favourites_count']
   r['listed_count'] = entry['listed_count']
   r['contributors_enabled'] = entry['contributors_enabled']
   r['description'] = entry['description']
   r['protected'] = entry['protected']
   r['location'] = entry['location']
   r['lang'] = entry['lang']
   // NOT EVERY ID WILL HAVE A 'URL' KEY, SO CHECK FOR ITS EXISTENCE WITH IF CLAUSE
   if 'url' in entry['entities']:
       r['expanded_url'] = entry['entities']['url']['urls'][0]['expanded_url']
   else:
       r['expanded_url'] = ''
   print(r)
   // CREATE EMPTY LIST
   lst = []
   // ADD DATA FOR EACH VARIABLE
   for f in fields:
       lst.append(str(r[f]).replace("\/", "/"))

   // WRITE ROW WITH DATA IN LIST
   //outfp.write(string.join(lst, "\t").encode("utf-8") + "\n")
   outfp.write("\t".join(lst).encode('utf-8') + '\n')

outfp.close()
```

**The error message**

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-441137b1bb4d> in <module>()
     37     #WRITE ROW WITH DATA IN LIST
     38     #outfp.write(string.join(lst, "\t").encode("utf-8") + "\n")
---> 39     outfp.write("\t".join(lst).encode('utf-8') + '\n')
     40 
     41 outfp.close()

TypeError: can't concat str to bytes
```

Any idea on how to fix this? The version of Python is 3.6.5 
Your help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

**Edite:**

This screenshot of part of my file after I opened the output file in the binary mode

[image: screenshot of part of my file after I opened the output file in the binary mode]

Comment: You attempt to concatenate a bytes object (the result of `join`) with a string. Change `'\n'` to `b'\n'` or encode after concatenation, not before.

Comment: It works but now I get another error from the same code line. The error  write() argument must be str, not bytes

Comment: Open the output file in the binary mode

Comment: I did but the output file become strange, I edit my post to post screenshot of part of the file

Answer (score 1):

```
outfp.write("\t".join(lst).encode('utf-8') + '\n')
```

After you do `.encode()` on a string you get an instance of `bytes`. You can't add another string (like `\n`) to `bytes`. That's what the error is telling you.

So you need to add the `\n` before you encode the string. Like below:

```
outfp.write(("\t".join(lst) + '\n').encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: It works but now I get another error from the same code line. The error write() argument must be str, not bytes

Comment: You must have the file opened in text mode. You can remove the `.encode()` part from that line & pass `encoding='utf-8'` when opening the file